# NullReferenceException When Using a ViewModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to use a ViewModel in my ASP.NET MVC project, but whenever I use it, I get a null reference error for some reason. The latest situation where I have this problem, is here (it works fine when I use the Model itself, but when I use the ViewModel, I get that error):

My Model:

```
public string FirstName { get; set; }
public string LastName { get; set; }
public string Gender { get; set; }
public string MaritalStatuse { get; set; }
public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
```

My ViewModel:

```
public class PersonFormViewModel
    {
        public Person Person { get; set; }

        public string Title
        {
            get
            {
                if (Person != null && Person.Id != 0)
                    return "Edit";
                return "New";
            }
        }
    }
```

My Controler:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            var person = _context.Persons.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == id);
            var viewModel = new PersonFormViewModel
            {

                Person =
                {
                    FirstName = person.FirstName,
                    LastName = person.LastName,
                    Gender = person.Gender,
                    DateOfBirth = person.DateOfBirth,
                    MaritalStatuse = person.MaritalStatuse
                }

            };
            return View(viewModel);
        }
```

When running this code, the "viewModel" in the Controller is null, even though the "person" is not. Can anyone please help me with this? (I am new to ASP.NET, as you might've guessed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Person needs to be instantiated before assigning values to it.

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    var person = _context.Persons.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == id);
    var viewModel = new PersonFormViewModel
    {

        Person = new Person
        {
            FirstName = person.FirstName,
            LastName = person.LastName,
            Gender = person.Gender,
            DateOfBirth = person.DateOfBirth,
            MaritalStatuse = person.MaritalStatuse
        }

    };
    return View(viewModel);
}
```